# luhn algorithm and 'digit manipulation' in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stringstream

In generating the 'check digit' in Luhn's algorithm

> The check digit (x) is obtained by computing the sum of digits then computing 9 times that value modulo 10 (in equation form, (67 * 9
>   mod 10)). In algorithm form: Compute the sum of the digits (67).
>   Multiply by 9 (603). The last digit, 3, is the check digit.

Natural instincts point towards taking an id as a string to make individual digit operation easier. But there seems to be no way to extract a digit at a time through stringstream since there's no delimiter(as far as I can tell). So the process turns into a cumbersome conversion of individual characters to ints...

There's modulus for each digit approach as well, which also takes a bit of work.

I guess what I'm getting at is that I feel maybe I'm overlooking a more elegant way taking an input and operating on the input as if they were single digit inputs.

Comment: Converting individual digit characters to ints isn't all that cumbersome: `int val = digit_char - '0';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modular arithmetic to simply the equation like following :-

```
checkdigit = (sum_digits*9)%10
           = ((sum_digits)%10*9)%10
```

Now `sum_digits%10` is very simple to evaluate using strings.

**C++ implementation :-**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  char* str = new char[100];
  cout<<"Enter the String: ";
  cin>>str;

  int val = 0;

  for(int i=0;str[i]!=0;i++) {

        val = (val+str[i]-'0')%10;   

  }

  val = (val*9)%10;

  cout<<"Checkdigit("<<str<<") = "<<val;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: that bit ..str[i]-'0' is one of those "why didn't I think of that"... man I feel like an idiot. Thanks for this snippet. It like that feeling you have when you reach for you calculator to multiply something by 10

Answer (score 0):

Stringstream has to calculate all digits and then convert each digit to a char by adding '0'. You'd have to subtract '0' again to get the digit values back. You'd be better off using the modulo approach directly.